# Bloquear navegadores antigos

Tags: html, navegador-de-internet

Existe alguma forma de bloquear *navegadores* antigos?
Pra ser mais direto: não deixar esses navegadores, tais como **IE 6** acessarem meu site?
Dei uma pesquisada na *internet* e não encontrei nenhuma fonte sobre esse assunto.

Comment: Já testou https://github.com/burocratik/outdated-browser ?

Comment: Vou testa-lo agora, eu não sabia que o mesmo existia;

Comment: Usado e aprovado...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você não colocou a tag [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), mas existem projetos interessantes que podem lhe ajudar:

- https://github.com/burocratik/outdated-browser

Para usar inclua o css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="your_path/outdatedbrowser/outdatedbrowser.min.css">
```

Include plugin's script at the bottom of the HTML body:

O js:

```
<script src="your_path/outdatedbrowser/outdatedbrowser.min.js"></script>
```

Paste the required HTML at the end of your document (see demo examples):

E crie este elemento:

```
<div id="outdated"></div>
```

Para chamar use:

```
//event listener: DOM ready
function addLoadEvent(func) {
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
        window.onload = func;
    } else {
        window.onload = function() {
            if (oldonload) {
                oldonload();
            }
            func();
        }
    }
}
//call plugin function after DOM ready
addLoadEvent(function(){
    outdatedBrowser({
        bgColor: '#f25648',
        color: '#ffffff',
        lowerThan: 'transform',
        languagePath: 'your_path/outdatedbrowser/lang/br.html'
    })
});
```

Idiomas suportados: https://github.com/burocratik/outdated-browser/tree/develop/outdatedbrowser/lang

Exemplos: https://github.com/burocratik/outdated-browser/tree/develop/demo

Comment: Isto me salvou, obrigado... fiz o teste pelo IE6 e funcionou,